# How to find the starting index of the first longest set of consecuitve duplicates inside an array

Tags: c++

Given

```
int array[5] = { 0, 0, 1, 1, 1 }
```

where the array can be any possible permutation of 0 and 1 and there is always at least one 1, I want to find the starting index of the (first) longest set of consecutive 1.
Examples:

```
int array[5] = { 0, 1, 1, 0, 0 } -> index = 1
int array[5] = { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 } -> index = 0
int array[5] = { 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 } -> index = 0
int array[5] = { 1, 0, 0, 1, 1 } -> index = 3
```

It can also be an array of char if it makes it easier. If I'm not clear please do tell me.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: "I want to find... " isn't a **question**.  This just looks like you have posted some requirements and are hoping someone will write some code for you, which isn't how this site works.

Comment: I will keep it in mind for the next time. I was not able to get even close to a decent result, so I thought it was useless to post the ones I tried.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about performance, then this trivial implementation should work for you.

```
int index = -1, candidate_index = -1;
size_t array_size = 5, max_size = 0; 
for (size_t i = 0; i < array_size; ++i) {
    if (array[i] == 0) {
        if (candidate_index >= 0) {
             size_t candidate_size = i - candidate_index + 1;
             if (candidate_size > max_size) {
                  max_size = candidate_size;
                  index = candidate_index;
             }
        }
        candidate_index = -1;
        continue;
    }
    // array[i] == 1 there
    if (candidate_index < 0) {
        candidate_index = i; 
    }
} 
// handling if the largest strip is at the end of the array
if (candidate_index >= 0) {
     size_t candidate_size = array_size - candidate_index;
     if (candidate_size > max_size) {
          index = candidate_index;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that only visits each index once.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    // int array[] = {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1};
    int array[] = {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0};
    int size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
    
    int max_length = 0;
    int max_index = -1;
    int last_value = 0;
    int temp_index = -1;
    // loop through looking for 0->1 and 1->0 transistions
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        if (last_value==0 && array[i]==1)
        {
            printf("Found the start of consecutive ones at index=%d\n", i);
            temp_index = i;
        }
        if (last_value==1 && array[i]==0)
        {
            printf("Found the end of consecutive ones at index=%d\n", i);
            printf("These consecutive ones have length=%d\n", i-temp_index);
            if (i-temp_index > max_length)
            {
                printf("Updating: larger than the maximum length of %d\n", max_length);
                max_length = i-temp_index;
                max_index = temp_index;
                printf("The new maximum length consecutive ones is index=%d length=%d\n", max_index, max_length);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Ignoring: not larger than the maximum length of %d\n", max_length);
            }
            temp_index = -1;
        }
        last_value = array[i];
    }
    // if the array ends with a 1 then there was no 1->0 transistion
    // so we need to check that here
    if (last_value == 1)
    {
        printf("The array ends with consecutive ones\n");
        printf("These consecutive ones have length=%d\n", size-temp_index);
        if (size-temp_index > max_length)
        {
            printf("Updating: larger than the maximum length of %d\n", max_length);
            max_length = size-temp_index;
            max_index = temp_index;
            printf("The new maximum length consecutive ones is index=%d length=%d\n", max_index, max_length);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Ignoring: not larger than the maximum length of %d\n", max_length);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Try it here: https://onlinegdb.com/r1ZF9bsbO

Comment: Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to just presenting code, I want to give some explanations.

The problem should be solved by using the **Sliding Window Pattern**

Such type of questions are typcically asked in job interviews, on learning sites or even on online contest sites.

The described problems are based on consecutive data structures like `std::array` or `std::vector`, or even other sturctures that are iterable.

And in all these questions you need to find some "longest" or "smallest" or "meeting a condition" subset of the original arrays (or others). Sometimes there are additional indirections, like in your case, where we need to find the start index of such a sub array.

So basically you can do a brute force approach with double or triple nested loops. Starting at index 0, count all consecutive one's in a nested loop. Then continue the outer loop with index 1 and so on and so one. The time complexity is then ofen O(n^2) or O(2^n) or maybe a even worse time complexity.

The better approach is the so called **Sliding Window**. With that you can achieve a time complexity of O(n), because we will touch each array element only one time. The space complexity is even O(1), so, completely independent from the number of elements.

The name **Sliding Window** already gives a hint for the solution. You check element by element, and if a sub structure meets a special condition, then we span a window over that subset. Example:

```
            Window Open        Window close       Window Open  Window close
                |                   |                   |       |
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
```

So, condition for Window open: Go through the array, element by element, an if we find a transition from 0 to 1, meaning, the previous element was 0 and the current element is 1, then the window is opened. It will be open as long as we have 1's. With the next 0 it will close. And so on and so on.

The width of the window is the number of 1's in such an open window. So, this we can count. And we can also simply calculate the max value. Everytime, when a window is closed, then we compare the current window width with the current max value. If it is bigger, then we store the current width as new max value. Additionally, because that is the question of this problem here, we store the start index of the window, if it is bigger than the previous one. At the end, we have then the needed index.

Please see one possible implementaion below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// Calculate longest sub array with all 1's index 
size_t startIndexOfLongestConsecutive1s(const std::vector<int>& data) {
    size_t startIndex{}, counter{}, previousValue{},maxCounter{}, startIndexMax{};

    // Go through all elements of the array
    for (size_t i{}; i <= data.size(); ++i) {

        // Get the current element. Special Handling for last element
        const size_t value = (i < data.size()) ? data[i] : 0u;
        
        // If we see a 1, then we are in a open sliding window
        if (value == 1) {

            // If the window was just opened, then remember the start index
            if (previousValue == 0) startIndex = i;

            // Count the number of 1's in the open window. This will be the width at the end
            ++counter;
        }
        else {
            // If the last window size is bigger than whatever we had before
            // Now, the value is 0. So the window is closed.
            if ((previousValue == 1) && (counter > maxCounter)) {
                // Store new max window size and new start index for max.
                maxCounter = counter;
                startIndexMax = startIndex;
            }
            // Optimization: If the maximum size of a found window is bigger 
            // than the rest of the remaining value, we can stop all activities
            if (maxCounter >= data.size() / 2) break;

            // Counter is 0 again
            counter = 0;
        }
        previousValue = value;
    }
    return startIndexMax;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> testData{
        {0,1,1,0,0},
        {1,0,0,0,0},
        {1,0,1,0,1},
        {1,0,0,1,1},
    };
    for (const auto& td : testData) {
        std::cout << startIndexOfLongestConsecutive1s(td) << " --> ";
        for (const auto& i : td) std::cout << i << ' '; std::cout << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```